# How can I get the stripe information?

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

I am trying to append certain information from the stripe object, but I am getting the error `Ambiguous use of subscript`. How do I fix it? I have more than one card stored in stripe, and when I print success I am getting all the information of my cards, I am not posting the console for security reasons. It also crashes at the `print(success![i])` line

```
    if let stripecust = object["Stripe"] as? String{
    PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("Customer", withParameters: ["customerId" : stripecust]) { (success: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if(error == nil){
                print(success)

  for(var i = 0; i < success?.count; i++){
 print(success![i]) //crashes here with error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
            if let type = success!["data"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] //error here {
                self.cardtype.append(String(type[i]["brand"]!)) 

 }

    if let numbercard = success!["data"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] //error here {

    self.lastfour.append(String((numbercard[i]["last4"]!)))

 }

 if let holdercard = success!["data"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] //error here{

 self.cardholder.append(String(holdercard[i]["name"]!))

 }



   }


    }else{
    print(error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least two problems here.

Your block declaration gives us the type `success: AnyObject?` so `success` is an optional `AnyObject` and that's all we can assume about it.

1. Everywhere you use `success!` you are force-unwrapping that optional, declaring that you *know* it will not be nil at that point. Your `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` error shows that this is not a safe or valid assumption. It appears there are cases when `error` is nil but `success` is also nil. You need to handle that or at least check for it more carefully (guard statements and optional binding are great tools for this sort of check).
2. `success!["data"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]` is not a valid statement given that `success` has type `AnyObject?`. `AnyObject` does not support the subscript operator. It's possible that `success` is also of a more specific type which support subscripting but right now there's no way for the compiler (or those of us reading your question) to know that. It looks like `success` is a dictionary with a String "data" key so one option would be to cast it before attempting to use a subscript:

---

```
if
    let successDictionary = success? as? [String: AnyObject],
    let data = successDictionary["data"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]
{
    ...
}
```